# Injecting object element into HTML - ActiveX

Tags: javascript, html, activex, html-object

I have trying to integrate my form with ActiveX object and i see strange behavior. when i am adding the object element hard coded to the html

```
<OBJECT id="PlayerComponentX" style="LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 362px; TOP: 0px; HEIGHT: 259px"
    data=data:application/x-oleobject;base64,C8E7L7ZFLUeFnCABl+fZxwAIAABqJQAAxRoAAA==
    classid=clsid:77783738-750A-4DD4-BF01-BB5D5DF0791A VIEWASTEXT></OBJECT>
```

i am able to geteklementbyid and call the component functions how ever when i am injecting the object element at run time

```
 var objElement = document.createElement('object');
        objElement.classid = 'clsid:2F3BC10B-45B6-472D-859C-200197E7D9C7';
        objElement.id = 'PlayerComponentX1';
        objElement.name = objectId;
        objElement.data = 'data:application / x - oleobject; base64, C8E7L7ZFLUeFnCABl + fZxwAIAABqJQAAxRoAAA =='; 
        this.config.element.appendChild(objElement);
```

and doing the same i failed and get exception

Comment: Your coding is not the same for both cases. objElement.name = objectId - where is objectId value stored? The objElement.data contains additional spaces that are invalid.

Comment: the objectid is random generated, i have removed the spaces and still getting Object doesn't support property or method 'InitManager' when i call the function

Comment: @li-raz, have you tried using `insertAdjacentHTML` with the same literal content as in your first case, instead of `createElement`?

Comment: hi, thats works, what is the difference?

Comment: @li-raz, can't tell what's the difference. Guess that's specific to how `object` element gets initialized by IE. Or, it could be specific to your particular ActiveX object.